# can anybody suggest bootstrap class for two column height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns with panel and contents are different. I want to display two columns in same height. Can anybody suggest how to accomplish this?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  

     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap 4 For this.Check the snippet.

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">



</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
                    ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum
                    lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum orem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Check this on Fullview mode.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);">
  <div class="h-25 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 25%</div>
  <div class="h-50 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 50%</div>
  <div class="h-75 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 75%</div>
  <div class="h-100 d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height 100%</div>
  <div class="h-auto d-inline-block" style="width: 120px; background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1)">Height auto</div>
</div>
```

You should have tried this for your problem or in another way you need to calculate height dynamically right side of your column for fixed height for both columns then you can achieve what you want.